# Batch update Opportunity with triggers on it

Tags: apex, batch, scheduled-apex, governorlimits

I want to run a batch update of Opportunities. I have simple criteria as you can see below.
B/c there is legacy code on the opportunity I want to run the updates one at a time to avoid limits I see hit when batches fire.
Please advise on running like this and making schedulable. Thanks!

```
 list <Opportunity> oops = [
select id, name from opportunity 
where probability > 89 and 
    CALENDAR_YEAR(StartDate__c)  =: System.today().year() ];
system.debug(oops);

for (Opportunity o: oops){
    database.update(o, false);
}
```

OR

```
database.update(oops,false);
```

Comment: Oops just seems like a word you really don't want associated with your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never ever ever do this:

```
for (Opportunity o: oops){
    database.update(o, false);
}
```

DML on a loop will get you into limit trouble a lot faster than anything else. The right way to fix this is with a batch.

Use batches instead. First, create a batch like below (it will also make your batch schedulable via the "Schedule Apex" button)

```
public without sharing class myBatchable Implements Database.Batchable<sObject>, Schedulable {

    public myBatchable () {

    }

    public void execute(SchedulableContext sc){
       myBatchable myBatch = new myBatchable();
       Database.executeBatch(myBatch, 1);  //Or whatever batch size you want
    }

    public List<Opportunity> start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {

        return [select id, name from opportunity where probability > 89 and CALENDAR_YEAR(StartDate__c)  =: System.today().year()];
    }

    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Opportunity> scope) {
        //Do whatever you want here with your objects

        database.update(scope,false);
    }

    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {

    }

}
```

Then, call it changing your batch size appropriately or simply schedule it.

```
Database.executeBatch(new myBatchable(), 1); //Or whatever batch size you want
```

PS: apologies for any typos, I am copy-pasting from previous code

Comment: thanks, that's it, I knew the for loop dml was poor form, batchable is what I was looking for